# How to get logged-in username of machine who sent HttpRequest to server(website)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, httprequest, wmi

We have deployed .net web application on server, whenever any http Request sent from client machine. I want logged in username of **client machine**, (not logged-in user of application).
Client and server both are in same domain.

eg. I have logged-in my machine with domain\username. I hit any website url on browser say [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com). Then it should show 'domain\username' in response or show on webpage.

Is it possible?

For ref-Below lines gives me server machine user name, **but I want client machine user name.**

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
Environment.UserName;
windowsIdentity.Name;
```

Comment: [How to implement Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to add information about domain/username to custom header in HTTP request and then read this header on server side, but I think you can't get such info on client side using browser so answer is no, this is not possible when using browser.

Comment: Is there any another way to get this info?

Comment: Either implementing Windows auth, as @stuartd suggested above either to build custom client side application which will consume BE API.